# Equivalence of Recursively Enumerability (RE) definitions

Tags: computability, semi-decidability

Let A be a subset of N <sup>n</sup>

Definition1 of RE

DEF1_RE = A is RE iff there is a TM M st M(x) = 1 iff x belongs to A, 0/undefined otherwise

Definition2 of RE

DEF2_RE = A is RE iff there is a recursive/Turing-decidable relation R subset of N<sup>n+1</sup> st

```
x belongs to A <=> there exists a y R(x,y)
```

So I have proved that
    if A belongs to DEF2_RE, then A belongs to DEF1_RE

but I can't prove the other direction. Can someone please help me prove the other direction?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  We want to help you with your (conceptual) problem, but as it's not clear what exactly your problem is, it's hard to help you.  (If you just want someone to solve your exercise/problem for you, this probably isn't the right site for that.)

Comment: Hey D.W. This wasn't a homework question. I was just trying it out for fun. I just couldnt think of a recursive relation R to make the other side work.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 1):

"For the other direction, let R(x,y) hold iff y codes a halting
computation with output 1 of M on input x." (A friend's answer)